# jQuery to find height of H3 after each prepend has added them all

Tags: javascript, jquery

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here? I have tried adding within the each as well but ended up being like 415px in height which was incorrect as only 2 lines of text so should be around 40px.

As you will see it creates the H3 heading in the each, but what I need to do after the the each is complete is find the highest heading so I can then set the height of all the others.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // rebuild product options display
  $('.rebuild_options .ty-product-options .ty-product-options__item').each(function(i, obj) {
    var option_title = $(this).find('.ty-product-options__item-label').text().replace(":", "");
    var option_html = $(this).find('.ty-product-options__item-label span a').attr('title');
    var $option_content = $(option_html);
    var option_html_text = $option_content[0].innerHTML;
    var option_html_img = $option_content[1].innerHTML;

    $(this).find('.ty-product-options__box').hide();
    $(this).find('.ty-product-options__item-label').addClass('input-text cm-hint');
    $(this).find('.ty-product-options__item-label').attr('title',option_html_text);
    $(this).find('.ty-product-options__item-label').html(option_html_img);
    $(this).find('.ty-product-options__item-label').prepend('<i class="option-status-icon ty-icon-star-empty"></i>');
    $(this).find('.ty-product-options__item-label').prepend("<h3 class='option-heading'>"+option_title+"</h3>");
  });

  var maxHeight = 0;
  $('.ty-product-options__item-label h3').each(function(i, obj) {
    if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) {
      maxHeight = $(this).height();
    }
    $(this).height(maxHeight);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.ty-product-options__item-label h3').each(function(i, obj) {
    if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) {
      maxHeight = $(this).height();
    }
  }).height(maxHeight);
```

You should assign the height to all h3's after calculating max by chaining it after the each function.

Comment: I tried replacing your solution with mine but seems to be setting all the heights as 0?